# How do I set up my dual-boot menu after I reinstall Windows?

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu after Windows 7, Then I used to have a menu that let me choose Windows or Ubuntu.

Then for obvious reasons I need re-install windows again, then I lost my dual boot. 
My computer start windows without ask me nothing.

Answer (score 3):

boot from a live CD, then in a terminal run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

this will run a graphical program that will repair your boot loader

source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

Boot the Ubuntu CD again and re-install grub. You can do this graphically with `boot-repair`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair for details.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you can just use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/download.php?id=1). It gives a really beautiful way of managing your boot menu and provides some interesting boot options that you may not easily encounter otherwise.

Alternatively, you can recover your regular grub booting with a utility such as the [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/).

There are further options, but those two are the easiest and work just fine.

Comment: vanjoe gave a decent approach - I've used that method and some similar approaches before with general success. Still, just use EasyBCD, it's great.